# Problem with *ngIf watching for observable changes and re-create/re-render child

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component that is watching for a change in observable returned object for complete child re rendering

so i have something similar to below

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someobject | async">
     <child [someobject]="someobject">
</ng-container>
```

I have no problem getting value changes render to child, but `*ngIf` only re render child if the value toggle from true to false, are there ways to enforce re render upon someobject value change. Because i try to avoid logic in `ngOnChanges` for dumb components which use onPush change detection

UPDATE --

> I am looking for a total re render/re creation i.e destory->create of the child here upon
>   input changes

stackbliz to demo 
stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfxc6f

Comment: Why do you need to re-render the complete component? Using ``ngIf`` with an async pipe is the same as normal but with the observable value, will only be false if the object if false, undefined, null, etc.

Comment: it won't re-render if someobject change from a truthy value to another truthy value and that's not what i want

Comment: I know, I was just asking why you need to re-render the complete component, and telling you it's not possible in that way, because usually when you need to re-render the complete object is a bad design problem.

Comment: Updated my question  to clarify

Comment: Anyway I don't get why you need to destroy an recreate the component, you have an observable as input parameter, it will update although you use ``onPush``, that's the way to do it, with observables.

Comment: You mean @Input someObject:Observable<any>?

Comment: your child component does use OnPush strategy?

Comment: Your forked stackblitz working example here is... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aiv5yq?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: The child will render when the value is set to true, it won't render at all when it's false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with default `*ngIf` directive because if you see in `*ngIf` directive implementation it caches the viewRef once it is defined and that's the reason you won't be able to re-render your template. Please refer this [line](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L196) in angular repo.

***Solution*** : You can create your own structural directive, where you prefer not to cache the viewRef and re-render always or on any condition you might like.
[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-espfcf?file=src/app/app.module.ts) for your reference.

Thanks

Comment: I think custom directive is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

It should be achievable hacking `*ngFor`, instead of `*ngIf`:

```
this.someObjectAsArray = this.someobject.pipe(map(x => [x]));

someTrackingFn = // put something appropriate here
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let obj of (someObjectAsArray | async); trackBy: someTrackingFn">
     <child [someobject]="obj">
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the async pipe on your child components input binding, or do you have an observable as input binding?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someobject | async">
  <child [someobject]="someobject | async"></child>
</ng-container>
```

Otherwise you could prefix your observable with the conventional `$` sign and do something like `*ngIf="someobject$ | async as someobject"`. Then you can pass your object without the async pipe on the child.